# how to create an impossible sudoku detector?

Tags: python-3.x, backtracking, sudoku

I'm making a sudoku solver on pygame, using backtracking. It's working, both the backtracking and the gui, however, when the user tries to solve an impossible puzzle, the game freezes.

I want to make a modification to my algorithm that, when the puzzle is impossible, the algorithm **detects** it, warning the user and reseting the board.

For now, this is the main code for the board class.

```
class Board:

    solvedBoard = [[0 for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]
    gameRunning = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.tabuleiro = [[0 for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]

    def reset(self):
        self.tabuleiro = [[0 for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]
        self.gameRunning = True

    def show(self):
        for i in self.tabuleiro:
            for j in i:
                print(j, end = ' ')
            print('')

    def setCell(self, linha, coluna, valor):
        self.tabuleiro[linha][coluna] = valor

    def isFull(self):
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if self.tabuleiro[i][j] == 0:
                    return False
        return True

    def numberPossibilities(self, linha, coluna):
        possible = [1 for i in range(10)]

        #horizontal check
        for col in range(9):
            if self.tabuleiro[linha][col]:
                possible[self.tabuleiro[linha][col]] = 0

        #vertical check
        for line in range(9):
            if self.tabuleiro[line][coluna]:
                possible[self.tabuleiro[line][coluna]] = 0

        #mini square check
        linhaSquare = (linha // 3) * 3
        colunaSquare = (coluna // 3) * 3
        for l in range(linhaSquare, linhaSquare + 3):
            for c in range(colunaSquare, colunaSquare + 3):
                if self.tabuleiro[l][c]:
                    possible[self.tabuleiro[l][c]] = 0

        toTry = []
        for k in range(1, 10):
            if possible[k]:
                toTry.append(k)

        return toTry

    def solve(self):
        self.show()
        print('')
        if self.isFull():
            for i in range(9):
                for j in range(9):
                    self.solvedBoard[i][j] = self.tabuleiro[i][j]
            self.gameRunning = False
            self.tabuleiro = self.solvedBoard
        elif self.gameRunning:
            found = False
            linha = 0
            coluna = 0
            for i in range(9):
                for j in range(9):
                    if (not self.tabuleiro[i][j]):
                        linha = i
                        coluna = j
                        found = True
                        break
                if found:
                    break
            numbers = self.numberPossibilities(linha, coluna)
            print(*numbers)
            print('')
            tamanho = len(numbers)
            for k in range(tamanho):
                if (not self.gameRunning):
                    self.tabuleiro = self.solvedBoard
                    break
                self.tabuleiro[linha][coluna] = numbers[k]
                self.solve()
            if (self.gameRunning):
                self.tabuleiro[linha][coluna] = 0
```

Note that the "show" function is only for debugging. I have an actual drawGrid function for handling the GUI.

My idea is to detect the first cell that needs to be changed, and, when the backtracking eventually comes back to It, with no other options to continue, It resets the board and then turns on a flag called "Impossible". Next iteration, the board detects that "Impossible" is on and resets the board, besides breaking the recursion.

However, that's seems too complicated, and I'm not sure how to do It without damaging code readability

What do you think? And also, Thanks in advance! This community is helping me a lot of this project :)

Comment: It would be easier if you could post the entire code, so we can test it running.

Comment: Hey, thanks for  wanting to help, however, I fixed the problem. I simply forbade the user of making illegal moves, and Also did my exacly idea to solve the problem with impossible boards. If you, or anyone wants, I can give the code to my solve method, though.